# How to read the *original* source of an iframe, after it has loaded, from the cache

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe, browser-cache

The most generic way to describe this is that I want to fire only one network request, only after the client has seen a certain part of the viewport, and then use it and display it in an iframe, in the most efficient manner possible.

Given a DOM structured like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head />
  <body>
    ...
    <iframe loading="lazy" sandbox="" src="http://www.example.com" />
    <pre />
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to show the client, in the `pre` tag, what the source of the `iframe` above looks like.
The `iframe` element may host an arbitrary document, it may be textual or binary, all that is known is that the browser can display it.
The iframe's source URL is hosted on the same origin.

I am aiming to display what one would see by going to a Chromium "view-source:" URL, or similar.

Accessing the `.contentWindow` or `.contentdocument` properties may not be possible, as it is sandboxed entirely, but even if I could, the document's `outerHTML` would not be sufficient, and using an `XMLSerializer` would obviously change the output. Also, I believe that browsers are allowed to edit certain areas of a document, such as unnecessary whitespace, or formatting.

I had simply tried the following:

```js
document
.body
.querySelector("iframe")
.addEventListener(
    "load",
    async ( { currentTarget: { src } } ) => {
        const data = await fetch(
            src, {
                cache: "only-if-cached"
            }
        );

        // ... use data
    }, {
        passive: true,
        once: true
    }
);
```

Yet, the fetch failed. It seemed that the URL was not in the browser's cache, but I did not want to initiate a new network request, is there an efficient way that I could do this?

I was thinking of using an Intersection Observer as a potential solution because it would result in only one network request, but the code was pretty long, and it seemed to not have been working correctly (I am inexperienced with the observer).

Comment: Does the iframe have any additional content (images, stylesheets, etc) or is it self contained in just the HTML file? Also note that [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) takes a string `type` as the first argument

Comment: @Steve Oh, right, I left out the event, fixing right now.
As for the iframe's contents, might I ask why such information is relevant, and what it changes? The iframe is currently self-contained, but would it be different if it were not?

Comment: if the source is self contained, you might instead be able load the source via fetch and use [iframe.srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc) to set the source to "load" the iframe. This method might have performance implications, as the request only happens when the JavaScript gets executed.

Comment: @Steve Key problem with that is that the document is not HTML. I could use a blob URL too, as that was my backup plan, but then I would need a way to know when the user has reached the iframe, leading to an `Intersection Observer`, or some shim, which is what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: @xxh - reference your note to Steve, even if you were to use a Blob URL, the iframe would still contain a complete HTML document that includes HTML, HEAD, BODY and an IMG to hold the blob, assuming it is an image (because you said the content would be rendered in the browser.). I think Steve has the best solution - XHR the iframe content and place it in both places you want it.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Hmm... I guess it seems to be the only viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few potential things going on here with the event listener and the fetch request. Note to other readers that [lazy loading](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr) in iframes is only supported in Chrome/Chromium, Edge, and Opera as of this writing (November, 2020).

This answer is aimed to the questioner who wants to also use lazy loading to dynamically load content. If the concern is just about making a single network request, it could be done via a fetch request and setting the `src` of the iframe via Blob or data URIs or via `srcdoc`, or using Service Workers (explored a little bit below).

#### Frames Potentially Loading Before Adding Event Listeners

You add an event listener to your frame after it's declared, which can create problems if the frame loads before the script is evaluated (which may be the case if it is cached).

Normally, you could see if your frame is already loaded via the `contentWindow` or `contentDocument` property, and if so run your initialization code on those frames, but because the frame is sandboxed, those properties aren't accessible. What you can instead do is declare your handler ahead of time, and when you create your iframe declare it then:

```
async function loader(frame) {
    console.log(frame.src);
    // ...
}
```

```
<iframe src="frame.html" loading="lazy" sandbox="" onload="loader(this)"></iframe>
```

#### Using Same-Origin in fetch requests

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache), `only-if-cached` can only be used if the `mode` is set to `same-origin`, which should be okay in your situation since you said that the frame is the same origin. The fetch request would look something like:

```
await fetch(src, { mode: 'same-origin', cache: 'only-if-cached' });
```

#### The Result

`main.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .spacer {
        height: 200vh;
        background: lightgray;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      async function loader(frame) {
        var sourceCodeElementId = frame.dataset.code;
        var sourceCodeElement = document.getElementById(sourceCodeElementId);
        var response = await fetch(frame.src, {
          mode: 'same-origin',
          cache: 'only-if-cached'
        });
        if (response.status === 504) {
          // if it didn't load via cache, just get it normally
          response = await fetch(frame.src);
        }
        var text = await response.text();
        sourceCodeElement.textContent = text;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="spacer">Scroll Down</div>
    <iframe src="frame.html"
        loading="lazy"
        data-code="frame-source-code"
        sandbox=""
        onload="loader(this)">
    </iframe>
    <pre id="frame-source-code"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample `frame.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
Frame
</html>
```

#### Optionally/Alternatively Use Service Workers

If the concern is around network requests, you can use [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), alternatively, or additionally to the above fixes. It takes a bit of work to get them up and running, but they can give you a finer control over network requests. [Caching files](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker) is a common tutorial, so you should be able to find a decent amount of resources if you go that route.

Comment: I feel like such a fool. I never actually tried to catch the rejected promise thus I had never looked at the actual error. It literally said that it needed `mode: "same-origin"`. Thank you nonetheless, and may your alternative suggestions help others who come across the same problem. And the loading=lazy is to help out those who *do* support it, the others will have to live like they have forever.

Comment: @xxh, it happens to the best of us. Glad that you fixed the issue!